# Is tensoflow pow(x, y) differentiable by y?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, automatic-differentiation

Some of the tensorflow functions are only differentiable by some of the arguments.

I want to know if tf.pow(x, y) is differentiable by y? (I am pretty sure it is differentiable by x.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `tf.pow(x, y)` is differentiable by y in tensorflow.

You can test the following scenario.

```
x = tf.Variable(3.0)
y = tf.Variable(3.0)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  z = tf.pow(x, y)

dz_dy = tape.gradient(z, y)
```

`dz/dy` is `(x^y)*log(x)` so we should get a value of `(3^3)*(log(3))` which is exactly what we see with `tf`

```
dz_dy.numpy() = 29.662533
```

Comment: would you please explain in details how is this compiled? i am newbie to tensorflow and unable to figure out how does this results (29.662533). i executed the code and put x instead of y in dz_dy = tape.gradient(z, y) and i got different result!! how come that happened although both x and y hv same value (3.0)

Comment: If you change `tape.gradient(z, y)` to `tape.gradient(z, x)`, you are calculating dz/dx instead of `dz/dy` (both are partials).  The closed form solution is still simple to compute to verify the results:  `dz/dy = y * x ^(y-1)`.  The partial derivatives are not symmetric so we should not expect the same result.

Comment: well, this is very difficult to me as a newbie here. One more thing please, do we have to check every tf.ops whether it is differentiable or non-differentiable  before we use it in our model?